# Harry Potter fanfiction in which Harry is molested by Barty Crouch Jr

Tags: harry-potter, fan-fiction, severus-snape, sirius-black, barty-crouch-jr

I am looking for a specific fanfiction. It's rather old, I think 10 years+.

The third task doesn't end with Harry and Voldemort duelling but Voldemort takes him to his manor. The Death Eaters torture him. There, Barty Crouch Jr. is also present and has a weird fixation on Harry and ends up molesting him. Snape is present and finally rescues him, exposing his status as a spy. Later on, Harry is kidnapped a second time, this time with Sirius, and molested again by Barty Crouch Jr.

Comment: This wholesome adventure sounds like something the whole family could enjoy.

Comment: You can't add the answer to the question. Please post an answer instead.